# Найти массив в json строке, если он имеется

Tags: c#, json

Есть строки вида:

> "{"status":"OK","error":"","region":56,"date":"2021-09-02
> 12:00:00","items":["2021-09-02 14:44:21"]}"

Нужно например с помощью регулярного выражения проверить, содержит ли эта строка массив, то есть содержит ли она подстроку типа:

> [xxxxxxxx]

До, внутри и позади могут быть любые символы.
Пытался сделать это следующим образом:

```
Regex regexMas = new Regex(@"^.+\[.+\].+\}.+$");
regexMas.IsMatch(str);
```

Comment: `std::regex` в C++, а тут у вас код на C#. Регулярное выражение не отличит массива от строки с квадратными скобками.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, так мне и нужно определить есть ли подстрока формата ```[xxxxxxxx]```, чтобы потом вырезать эту подстроку

Comment: Но `"error":"[xx] Access denied."` вовсе не массив.

Comment: А почему как json не хотите его распарсить?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ну для начала можно выбрать все эти подстроки, а потом уже думать как определить какая из них массив

Comment: А десереализовать это пробовали? Это же просто должно быть.

Comment: @aepot, у меня на одном и том же месте может быть и ```[]``` и ```{}```, вот мне и нужно определиться как его десериализовать )

Comment: Напомните, какая версия дотнета у вас?

Comment: @aepot, asp net core 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json лучше парсить специально предназначенным для этого средствами.

Я уверен, для решения вашей задачи должен быть более адекватный способ, но если действовать по хардкору, а именно реально определить, какого же именно типа данные в `items`, то можно пойти вот таким вот путем:

```cs
private static JsonTokenType FindItemsToken(string json)
{
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName && reader.GetString() == "items")
            break;
    }
    if (!reader.Read())
        return JsonTokenType.None;
    return reader.TokenType;
}
```

Проверяем

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"error\":\"\",\"region\":56,\"date\":\"2021-09-02 12:00:00\",\"items\":[\"2021-09-02 14:44:21\"]}";
    string json2 = "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"error\":\"\",\"region\":56,\"date\":\"2021-09-02 12:00:00\",\"items\":{\"0\":\"2021-09-02 14:44:21\"}}";
    Console.WriteLine(FindItemsToken(json));
    Console.WriteLine(FindItemsToken(json2));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
StartArray
StartObject
```

Использовать это просто

```cs
JsonTokenType tokenType = FindItemsToken(json);
if (tokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
{
    // это массив
}
else if (tokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
{
    // это объект
}
else
{
    // это что-то другое или поле "items" не найдено
}
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
(?:"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"|[{}\s\w,:])*\[
```