# C# Перебор всех элементов многомерного массива

Tags: c#, массивы, json, foreach

Есть массив объектов, который я получаю при десериализации ответа от сервера (json), получается довольно много вложенностей, существует ли унифицированный способ(метод) перебрать все элементы данного массива, в данном случае мне нужно проверить все элементы на `null`.

Пример ответа от сервера:

```json
{
  "regionList": [
    {
      "ord": 1,
      "subwayLines": [
        {
          "isn": 1477671903,
          "stations": [
            {
              "isn": 1477963903,
              "name": "str"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: рекурсивно проходите и все

Comment: А смысл всей этой задачи в чем? Вам нельзя иметь null в модели, или для чего это все?

Comment: Нужно проверить тело ответа на null элементы, т.е если "ord": null - тест провален, и так нужно пройти весь полученный массив

Comment: Почему бы не сделать валидацию на уровне модели данных? Как я понял, только строки надо на null проверять и объекты. Сделайте на нужных свойствах сеттеры, которые при присваивании туда null будут бросать исключение. А в тесте просто проверяйте, выброшено исключение или нет.

Comment: Идея по рекурсии была в том, что сначала все эти вложенности я привожу к List, после чего проверяю элементы этого листа на null

Comment: довольно неплохой способ))), возможно это и есть решение для меня, просто хотел для пулла тестов сделать универсальный метод

Comment: Универсальный метод чего? Он моментально станет непригодным, как только вам потребуется разрешить где-то null.

Comment: Так что именно надо проверить - JSON на null или свойства модели на null? Какова истинная цель теста?

Comment: Цель теста в том, чтобы провалидировать ответ от сервера

Comment: Есть еще такой вариант, тупо искать null токен в json-е. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1324686/373567

Comment: Если нужна валидация, то проверки на null недостаточно. Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону json schema.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете ДОСТОВЕРНО проверить json ответ на наличие null в полях, т.к. поля содержащие null могут быть просто отброшены сериализатором и не попасть в json, а в структуре данных они есть.

Если вы не знаете структуру данных, то имхо, это плохая задача, но решается очень просто (на коленке с багами), через `(Contains(": null") || Contains(":null"))`, если конечно это вхождение не внутри строки, но даже тогда вы по сути проверите json внутри json =)

Есть более надёжный вариант, искать JsonToken, как предложил **aepot**, но описывать не буду, т.к. я им не пользовался. Но опять-же если сериализатор отбросит - то это вам не поможет.

Единственно правильный вариант - знать модель и корректно десериализовать, а уже методами в модели проверять на null. Можно даже через рефлексию, чтобы не плодить методы для каждого класса.